# Regex Pattern for Whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am creating a regex library to work with HTML (I'll post it on MSDN Code when it's done). One of the methods removes any whitespace before a closing tag.

```
<p>See the dog run </p>
```

It would eliminate the space before the closing paragraph. I am using this:

```
    public static string RemoveWhiteSpaceBeforeClosingTag(string text)
    {
        string pattern = @"(\s+)(?:</)";
        return Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "</", Singleline | IgnoreCase);
    }
```

As you can see I am replacing the spaces with </ since I cannot seem to match just the space and exclude the closing tag. I know there's a way - I just haven't figured it out.

Comment: FYI, both the Singleline and IgnoreCase modifiers are irrelevant, as there are no dots or letters in the regex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\s+(?=</)
```

is that expression you're after. It means one or more white-space characters followed by

- `(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This won't be included in the expression;
- `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). This will be included in the expression.

That all being said, regular expressions are a flaky and error-prone way of processing HTML so should be used with caution if at all.

Comment: That was it - thanks.

I wish there was an alternative to processing the HTML I'm getting. You should have seen the IndexOf and LastIndexOf code that this is replacing 8-\

Answer (score 3):

You want a lookahead (?=) pattern:

```
\s+(?=</)
```

That can be replaced with ""